# How to take spatial average of wind speed and wind average

Tags: r, vector, geospatial, spatial

I have large data set of multiple model outputs in which I receive U and V vectors for wind data. I want to add wind vectors to a map but since there is so many data points the vectors do not pick up the true direction of wind ([swirling vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqrkO.jpg)). I am thinking I need to take an average of a spatial buffer, per model output, in order to get true wind direction. I am also wondering if I need to do this with just the U and V vector or if it is acceptable to take the "spatial" average once I have converted the U and V vectors to wind speed and angles. I am struggling how to average this data to plot wind vectors on the map.

[vectors still swirling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYodA.png)

```
library(dplyr)
library(raster)

# sample for downloading and accessing raster file for U and V vectors for one model projection

url_ucomp <- paste0("https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_nam.pl?file=nam.t00z.awphys00.tm00.grib2&lev_10_m_above_ground&var_UGRD=on&subregion=&leftlon=238.596&rightlon=242.936&toplat=35.00&bottomlat=32.36&dir=%2Fnam.20220529")
download.file(url_ucomp, "gribfile_u", mode="wb")
wind_u <- raster("gribfile_u")

url_vcomp <- paste0("https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_nam.pl?file=nam.t00z.awphys00.tm00.grib2&lev_10_m_above_ground&var_VGRD=on&subregion=&leftlon=238.596&rightlon=242.936&toplat=35.00&bottomlat=32.36&dir=%2Fnam.20220529")
download.file(url_vcomp, "gribfile_v", mode="wb")
wind_v <- raster("gribfile_v")


#aggregating wind vectors to a courser resolution
agg_u_vecs <- raster::aggregate(wind_u, 3, mean) %>% 
  rasterToPoints() %>% 
  as.data.frame()

agg_v_vecs <- raster::aggregate(wind_v, 3, mean) %>% 
  rasterToPoints() %>% 
  as.data.frame()

# Joining U and V vector and averaging wind and angle per unique location
vec_data <- left_join(agg_u_vecs, agg_v_vecs, by = c("x", "y")) %>% 
  group_by(x,y) %>% 
  mutate(u = mean(u),
         v = mean(v))

# converting to knots and 0/360 degrees
vec <- vec_data %>%
  mutate(wind = ((sqrt((u^2) + (v^2)))),
         angle = atan2(u/wind, v/wind),
         angle = (angle * 180/pi) + 180) %>%
  dplyr::select(-c(u, v)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(x, everything()) %>% 
  mutate(wind = wind*1.94)

# pal info
wind_pal <- colorRampPalette(c( "#7635b8", "#3a57ba", "#4999b3","#5bc752", "#c9b84d", "#cc8247", "#ab3c4d", "#bf4182" ))

wind_limits <- c(0,50)

wind_values <- c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50)


# OLD CODe

#head()
wind_u_csv <- structure(list(x = c(-117.63543604636, -117.63543604636, -117.63543604636, 
-117.63543604636, -117.63543604636, -117.63543604636), y = c(35.567466886408, 
35.567466886408, 35.567466886408, 35.567466886408, 35.567466886408, 
35.567466886408), date = c("wind_u_00", "wind_u_03", "wind_u_06", 
"wind_u_09", "wind_u_12", "wind_u_15"), u = c(6.08053365874566, 
7.02658548082255, 4.64992272123721, 4.81868844838758, 5.65558956301594, 
11.5708419101172)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

#head()
wind_v_csv <- structure(list(x = c(-117.63543604636, -117.63543604636, -117.63543604636, 
-117.63543604636, -117.63543604636, -117.63543604636), y = c(35.567466886408, 
35.567466886408, 35.567466886408, 35.567466886408, 35.567466886408, 
35.567466886408), date = c("wind_u_00", "wind_u_03", "wind_u_06", 
"wind_u_09", "wind_u_12", "wind_u_15"), v = c(2.80885274740881, 
2.40782863930913, 1.56009484818043, -0.309935773323164, 0.0649002520881436, 
-0.322397307322153)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

wind_data <- left_join(wind_u_csv, wind_v_csv, by = c("x", "y")) %>% 
  dplyr::select(!c("date.y")) %>% 
  rename(date = date.x)
  
wind_data$date <- gsub("wind_u_", "", wind_data$date)
  

wind_ras <- wind_data %>%
  mutate(wind = ((sqrt((u^2) + (v^2)))),
         angle = atan2(u/wind, v/wind),
         angle = (angle * 180/pi),
         date = as.factor(date)) %>%
  dplyr::select(-c(u, v)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(x, everything()) %>% 
  relocate(wind, .before = date) %>% 
  mutate(wind = wind*1.94)

#joined U and V head() - above code output
wind_ras <- structure(list(x = c(-117.63543604636, -117.63543604636, -117.63543604636, 
-117.63543604636, -117.63543604636, -117.63543604636), y = c(35.567466886408, 
35.567466886408, 35.567466886408, 35.567466886408, 35.567466886408, 
35.567466886408), wind = c(12.994024322104, 12.6874410512174, 
12.1783158912536, 11.811549403526, 11.7969072069326, 11.8128047422468
), date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("00", 
"03", "06", "09", "12", "15", "18", "21", "24", "27", "30", "33", 
"36", "39", "42", "45", "48", "51", "54", "57", "60", "63", "66", 
"69", "72", "75", "78", "81", "84"), class = "factor"), angle = c(65.2058103800088, 
68.3969449081129, 75.6099087501852, 92.9179439634513, 89.3884797708515, 
93.0350501131036)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image: swirling vectors]

Comment: To show how to take a spatial average, we would need spatial data. You provide values for one location at different dates. Can you instead provide two rasters (u and v) and code for one date?

Comment: @RobertHijmans I just updated the script to include a sample of downloading one model projection for each U and V vector.

Comment: Can you now show how you create the map from these data?

Comment: @RobertHijmans I have now included more code in how I made the map. I left our resampling for a finer resolution and the shape files for masking the mainland and islands. The arrows are still swirling. Is my understanding or process for averaging vectors off? I have inserted a new updated photo of the vectors

Answer (score 0):

This is your example data

```
url_ucomp <- paste0("https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_nam.pl?file=nam.t00z.awphys00.tm00.grib2&lev_10_m_above_ground&var_UGRD=on&subregion=&leftlon=238.596&rightlon=242.936&toplat=35.00&bottomlat=32.36&dir=%2Fnam.20220529")
url_vcomp <- paste0("https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_nam.pl?file=nam.t00z.awphys00.tm00.grib2&lev_10_m_above_ground&var_VGRD=on&subregion=&leftlon=238.596&rightlon=242.936&toplat=35.00&bottomlat=32.36&dir=%2Fnam.20220529")
download.file(url_ucomp, "gribfile_u", mode="wb")
download.file(url_vcomp, "gribfile_v", mode="wb")
```

And here is how to do the computations you show

```
f <- function(u, v) { 
   wind = sqrt((u^2) + (v^2))
   angle = atan2(u/wind, v/wind) * (180/pi)
   wind = wind * 1.94
   x <- c(wind, angle)
   names(x) <- c("wind", "angle")
   x
}

library(terra)
u <- rast("gribfile_u")
v <- rast("gribfile_v")
w <- f(u, v)
```

You could aggregate the input first

circ_mean <- function(x) {
x = x * pi/180
atan2(mean(sin(x)), mean(cos(x))) * 180/pi
}

```
af <- 3
uu <- aggregate(u, af, mean)
vv <- aggregate(v, af, mean)
wa <- f(uu, vv)
```

You could also aggregate the wind direction, using the circular mean (here for radians)

```
circ_mean <- function(x) {
    atan2(mean(sin(x)), mean(cos(x)))
}
```

You do not show how you go from the data to your map, so I cannot comment more.

Comment: with inn the circular mean calculation, is the x variable the wind speed in my data? Or is that the angle after vector aggregation and calculations?

Comment: I got it all figured out. The biggest issue in my code was aggegating spatially then realizing my arrows were point towards the direction the wind was coming. Not the direction it was blowing. Thank you